# When is Shared Graphics Memory best utilized in real world use?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, graphics-card, vram

Say for example, I have a dedicated GPU with 2GB of VRAM and it has 8GB of shared memory from my 16GB system ram. Does that 8GB really have any influence at all when it comes to performance or what benefit does having that extra 8GB do?

When I looked it up, I saw that shared graphics memory is used when the dedicated VRAM is full in theory but in practice, how does that really matter in the grand scheme of things? If system memory is slower than VRAM, in what situations can I most see the benefit of the additional 8GB to my 2GB of VRAM? Playing games? Doing 3D modeling? Etc.

I just want to understand and know of examples when shared graphics memory is actually beneficial because for example, if the VRAM is full when playing a game and it utilizes the shared memory but the game starts lagging, doesn't that mean it's essentially useless since it didn't help with the performance so if that's not how it benefits me, then what else is it useful for?

Comment: It's slower, but it's more than 2 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible example is when you render a video in postproduction. Software (usually) try to use GPU and GPU memory as much as possible to speedup (and parallelize the process). So in this case you can benefit from shared VRAM because videos are huge so more is better.

Another usecase is when you do 3D render with considerable amount of textures. Usually software again try to put as much as possible in GPU memory to have faster access.